# How to request improvements to Excel from Microsoft?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Software vendors often have a "Suggest an idea" or "Request an ehancement" website where users can request improvements.

Question:

Does Microsoft have such as site?

For example, I want to request easier/out-of-box functionality for **formatting groups of rows** based on common values.

- I'm aware that it's possible to do that sort of thing by [creating a helper column and by using the `=ISODD` formula via conditional formatting](https://superuser.com/questions/938111/shading-groups-of-rows-based-on-changing-text-values). But I want something easier -- something that can be done with a click of a button.

Comment: I'd think their suggestions box for 2016 will now be closed. Their first response would be "Have you tried 2019?"

Comment: **Answer:** Send feedback using Microsoft's Feedback Portal: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/

Answer (score 2):

There is! Excel comes with a option called **Send a Suggestion!!**

1. **Just Click on Feedback**

[Here is a Image reference for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfNRa.png)

2. **You'll Get Something like this**

[Another Image Reference for ya](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6u7z.png)

3. **Click on *"I Have a Suggestion"* Option**
4. **Then, Write your suggestion :D**

*I Hope this Helps!*

Comment: Thanks! It's weird, I don't seem to have the feedback button in my version of Excel (2016).  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZgVQ.png

Comment: I was able to solve it via the registry editor: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/no-more-smiley/c6bf2770-9e2c-4f23-b921-6364237e51b8

Comment: oh great!! good for ya!

Comment: Do you mind me asking what version of Excel you were using -- where you saw the feedback button?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I didn't have the [feedback button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfNRa.png) in [my version of Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZgVQ.png) (2016).

I followed the steps in this article for adding a key to the registry:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/no-more-smiley/c6bf2770-9e2c-4f23-b921-6364237e51b8

> Create a "Feedback" key under
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common` and then
> create a DWORD called "Enabled", setting its value to 1.
>
> [image]

Now, the smiley face appears in the top right corner of Excel:

[image]

When I click the smiley face, I can choose the "Send a frown" button, which pops up the Microsoft Office Feedback window:

[image]

I believe I'll be able to request an enhancement via that feedback window.

Answer (score -1):

You can give a feedback to Microsoft about your requirement:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11

Microsoft values your opinion. Your feedback goes directly to our engineers and helps us shape the future of Microsoft products and services for all our users.