# Feedback button missing from Excel 2016 file menu

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel 2016 (Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016):

The Feedback button seems to be missing from the File menu:

[image]

---

I've heard that the menu ought to look like this:

[image]

---

Question:

How can I get the Feedback button to show up?

---

Related:

- [Smiley face is missing from top right corner in Excel](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/no-more-smiley/c6bf2770-9e2c-4f23-b921-6364237e51b8) ("No more smiley ?")
- [How to request improvements to Excel from Microsoft?](https://superuser.com/questions/1699872/how-to-request-improvements-to-excel-from-microsoft)

Answer (score 1):

The Feedback button can be obtained in C2R versions of Office, such as retail Office Professional Plus 2016, Office Home & Business 2016.

To judge whether Office is a C2R version, it depends on whether there is a button of Update Options under Product Information.

If you have volume license version of Office 2016 which is one of MSI version, you can not find this button.
[image]

To submit the request or feedback, I would suggest you post the threads on [Microsoft Feedback forum](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/).